# How can i loop my code?

Tags: javascript

My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var callnotification = function() {
  $.sticky('<b>TestA</b>');
  }
  setInterval(callnotification, 5000);
});
```

And i want to show different notifications, like: TestA, TestB, Test3 every 5000 seconds. I tried do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var callnotification = function() {
$.sticky('<b>TestA</b>');
}
setInterval(callnotification, 5000);

var callnotification = function() {
$.sticky('<b>TestB</b>');
}
setInterval(callnotification, 5000);

var callnotification = function() {
$.sticky('<b>TestC</b>');
}
setInterval(callnotification, 5000);

});
```

But it seems to multiply. I think thats becase functions are looping each other, and it shows notifications like:
    Test A
    Test B
    Test B
    Test B
    Test C
    Test B
    Test A
etc..

So.. how can i loop that? Lets say i want to loop from Test A to Test M and again from Test A to Test M.

Comment: I also tried to do something like this:
   `$(document).ready(function() {`

    var callnotification = function() {
    $.sticky('<b>TestA</b>');
    }
    setInterval(callnotification, 5000);
    });`

Comment: Stop overwriting you `callnotification` function!

Comment: Have one function that internally toggles between 3 notifications, kinda like picture gallery only instead of different images - different text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      var callnotification = function() {
      var counter = 65;
      $.sticky('<b>Test' + String.fromCharCode(counter++) + '</b>');
      }
      setInterval(callnotification, 5000);
    });
```

For Re-loop from M to A :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          var callnotification = function() {
          var counter = 65;
          $.sticky('<b>Test' + String.fromCharCode(counter++) + '</b>');
          if (counter == 78) {counter = 65};
          }
          setInterval(callnotification, 5000);
        });
```

Comment: The same problem like code from friend whose post is above. Its only displays 1 notification without looping. Just 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var i = 0;
var letters = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

var callnotification = function(msg) {
   $.sticky('<b>'+msg+'</b>');
}

var t = setInterval(function(){
   callnotification('Test'+letters[i%letters.length]);
   i++;
},5000);
```

**Snippet**:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPbpbm

Comment: Unfortunelly, its only displays 1 notification without looping. Just 1 time.

Comment: The problem is in your `sticky` function not in what we suggested!!!
Run the sinppet I have posted

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cu9bsmzU
Thats the sticky.js. I have to mention, that i already have jquery added.

Comment: @audiophonic in my case it prints them all. Look at the new snippet

Comment: I know that should work, bot its not :/ THe notification with "TestA" appears, and i cant even close it. Like there was a tons of notification on each other, and everytime i close one, 10 next appears. I think the're not multiplying, because sourcecode doesnt detect rest of notification. It shows 1 existing. I dont know what to do ;c

Comment: @audiophonic You want to have closable tool tips with Test from A to M ,right?

Comment: Yes. As you can see in sticky.js which code i posted in my last post, there is a function which close single notification every 5000 ms since its was showed. So i want to do something like this: http://pastebin.com/k145wBXq. Of couse closing function is alredy implemented.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion Sticky js is a poor library.

Use this one instead: [Notification Manager](https://github.com/kidwon24/Notification.menager/)

Here are are few examples for your case see which one fits you:

```
$(function() {
  var charCode = 65;

  setInterval(function() {

    var notification = window.createNotification();
    var msg = 'Test ' + String.fromCharCode(charCode++);
    notification.addMsg({
      text: msg, type: 'alert'
    });

    notification.render(null, function(notif) {
      // example 1
      notif.destroy(5000);

      /* example 2
          notif.destroy(5000, function() {
            var newNotif = window.createNotification();
            newNotif.addMsg({
              text: '(' + msg + ' is closed)',
              type: 'info'
            });
            newNotif.render();
          });
          */


      /* example 3
          var newNotif = window.createNotification();
          newNotif.addMsg({text:'('+msg+' is closed)', type:'info'});
          newNotif.render(5000);
          */
    });

    (charCode == 78) && (charCode = 65);
  }, 1000);
});
```